# Emacs, getting the output of the echo area

Tags: emacs

How can I insert directly the text displayed in the echo area? (also wrongly called the minibuffer).

When I for example run `(+ 2 2)` in a buffer and execute it with `C-x C-e` it correctly displays the result '2' in the echo area. There is also a '2' in the Messages buffer. I'd like this '2' inserted below the line executed, in the same buffer, or something like that.

Is there a command to, for example, pipe the echo area into the buffer or copy the last line of the Messages buffer into the present working buffer?

Comment: `C-u C-x C-e` will insert the result into the buffer. Not what you ask, but what you'd like in 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @Juancho: yes, that is what I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lisp-interaction-mode` which is the default mode for the `*scratch*` buffer you can use `eval-print-last-sexp` bound to `C-j`.

**Edit:**

In any buffer you can switch to `lisp-interaction-mode` with `M-x: lisp-interaction-mode [RET]`

Now `C-j` should be bound by default to `eval-print-last-sexp` unless the binding is shadowed by another mode.
You can check the quick description of the current major-mode with `C-h m`.

If it is shadowed or simply not bound you can eval

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'eval-print-last-sexp)`

with `C-x C-e`. That will bind the command to `C-c p`.

To make the change permanent write it in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: Isn't the default mode for `*scratch*` `Fundamental`? It is on my system. Or is that just a name for `lisp-interaction-mode`? Your `eval-print-last-sexp` works fine in Fundamental but C-j us not bound.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the EMACS `insert` commands. To accomplish what you illustrated in your simple example you would need to do the following.

```
(insert-string (number-to-string (+ 2 2)))
```